# How to write a catch-all (de)serializer for Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

Writing a custom serializer is pretty easy when you know the type in advance. For eg. `MyType` one can write a `MyTypeSerializer extends StdSerializer<MyType>`. See http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers

But, let's say that:

1. I have objects of several types (interfaces) going through Jackson serialization.
2. I don't know the type of theses objets in advance.
3. I can't add annotations on theses types.
4. all theses objets can be cast to a common type I know so that I can get its state data, type that is not part of their interface.

This means I need to write a Serializer that should handle all types ("catch-all") and can decide if it supports it (4.). I've naïvely tried a `CatchAllSerializer extends StdSerializer<Object>` but it's not triggered at all.

How do one write/register a serializer that will catch all types, can decide if it support a given type and provide serialization mechanism?

Comment: I use `ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString()`.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon this triggers default Jackson serialization but the question is about triggering a custom serializer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a [BeanSerializerModifier](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/BeanSerializerModifier.java) for the `ObjectMapper` to override all the bean serializers on your a delegating serializer that decides which form of serialization to use depending on the object type.

Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonSerializerModifier {
    public static interface A {

    }
    public static class B implements A {
        public String field1 = "value1";

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return field1;
        }
    }
    public static class C implements A {
        public String field2 = "value2";

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return field2;
        }
    }
    public static class D  {
        public String field3 = "value3";
    }

    private static class MyTypeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {
        private final JsonSerializer<Object> delegate;

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public MyTypeSerializer(JsonSerializer<?> delegate) {
            this.delegate = (JsonSerializer<Object>) delegate;
        }

        @Override
        public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
                throws IOException {
            if (value instanceof A) {
                jgen.writeString(value.toString());
            } else {
                delegate.serialize(value, jgen, provider);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.setSerializerModifier(new BeanSerializerModifier() {
            @Override
            public JsonSerializer<?> modifySerializer(SerializationConfig config,
                                                      BeanDescription beanDesc,
                                                      JsonSerializer<?> serializer) {

                return new MyTypeSerializer(serializer);
            }
        });
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(module);
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(Arrays.asList(new B(), new C(), new D())));
    }

}
```

Output:

```
["value1","value2",{"field3":"value3"}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Alexey. You got the idea and your code works if the test is `isAssignableFrom` but in my use case I need to have a handle on the object itself to see if my custom serializer will be able to serialize it, not only its class. Any clue?

Comment: In other words, instead of a `BeanDescription` I'd like to get a reference to the very instance of the object to serialize.