# How to extend Jackson property discovery in a "catch-all-types" way?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonschema

Following my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25015411/how-to-write-a-catch-all-deserializer-for-jackson) about serialization only, I'd like to go further and support `JsonFormatVisitor`.

I have the same requirements, that is:

1. I have objects of several types (interfaces).
2. I don't know the type of theses objets in advance.
3. I can't add annotations on theses types.
4. I can introspect all theses objets to get their state data.

Now that serialization works, I need to generate JsonSchema and hence do something like that:

```
SchemaFactoryWrapper visitor = WHAT?
mapper.acceptJsonFormatVisitor( mapper.constructType( Foo.class ), visitor );
JsonSchema jsonSchema = visitor.finalSchema();
String schemaString = mapper.writeValueAsString( jsonSchema );
```

I've implemented a `SchemaFactoryWrapper` that gets its `expectAnyFormat` called but I don't know what to do inside it. Looks like there's no schema for "any" objects.

Maybe I can hook elsewhere in jackson? Maybe it is possible to extends the whole Bean/Property introspection mechanism to support a completely different model (ie. not beans)?

I'm a bit lost, please help me find the treasure room :)

Answer (score 2):

I can try to suggest some approaches that may be helpful.

First, even if you can not annotate classes directly, "mix-in annotations" can help -- this does assume static knowledge, however

Second, since schema-generation uses type detection used for serialization, you may want to register custom serializers; but this does not necessarily mean having to hand-write all. The most flexible way to register custom serializers is via `Module` interface (mapper.registerModule(new MyModule()); Modules can register `Serializers` instance which gets called when trying to locate a `JsonSerializer` for a type for the first time (after this, instance is cached to be re-used for other properties of same type).
This is where you could configure and return your custom `JsonSerializer`; but it might only need to handle schema-related callback(s) (one(s) called by schema generator).

It is also possible to extend/modify property discovery mechanism; whether this is easier depends. But the thing to look for is registering `BeanSerializerModifier` via Module.
It gets called during construction of `BeanSerializer` (general POJO serializer used unless something more specific is registered), and with it you can add/modify properties; or just replace resulting serializer altogether (and also then allows chaining of custom serializer with default one, if needed).